# Why did two Black Mushrooms spawn in my game?

Tags: diablo-iii

While playing Diablo 3, my Wizard found a Black Mushroom on her first run-through of the Cathedral. I was totally stoked, of course, but then when I was playing with my Monk, another Black Mushroom spawned on his run-through.

At first I was excited, but then I was just really confused. Since you only ever need one Black Mushroom, and can't really get rid of one, why did two spawn? Is this a bug, or is there some purpose to it? I've included a screenshot of my Stash as evidence.

[image: Two Black Mushrooms in my Stash]

Comment: It's not a bug.  Just drop it or don't pick it up in the first place.

Comment: Don't you want to have a staff for each character? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Up until today's patch (1.0.3), you could lose your staff by dropping it.

The components therefore continue to have a chance to drop, else you'd never be able to replace a lost staff.

I've got half the drops for a second staff just from random luck.

Answer (score 6):

The black mushroom drop location is a random variant of a standard dungeon tile. The game doesn't block it from appearing just because you already have it.

D3 dungeons aren't attached to, or created for, particular players. You can roll a new dungeon, play it for a bit, make it public, and leave when someone else joins, and they could do the same thing. In theory, any number of players could pass through the same dungeon, and some of them might want a mushroom :)